# The fastest way to work with a large array of data in node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, performance, npm

I have some db with 4 000 000 numbers and I need to check if some number is exist in db

Database exapmle: `[177,219,245,309,348,436,...]`

I tried use mysql table but it takes **1300ms** for check if some **1** number is exist

It very long time and I`ve check some another ways:

1) Push all numbers to `array` and check it with `indexOf`

2) Push all numbers to `string` and check it with `indexOf`

3) Push all numbers to `object` and check it with `hasOwnProperty`

4) Push all numbers to `object` and check value

I`ve made 100 checks in all of this ways and measured the time:

```
try [...].indexOf(...) === 0
Total: 726ms

try String(...).indexOf(...) === 0
Total: 1915ms

try {...}.hasOwnProperty(...) === true
Total: 4ms

try {...}[...] === true === true
Total: 4ms
```

The code of tests:

```
// Reads db json with ~4 000 000 elements
var arr = utils.readJSON('members.json');
// Converts db to string type
var arr_string = arr.toString();
// Makes empty object
var arr_obj = {};
// Converts db to object type
for(var i in arr){
    arr_obj[arr[i]] = true;
}
// Makes empty array
var checkList = [];
// Gets 100 different values from different places of db
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    checkList.push(arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 100 * i)]);
}
// Main time variable
var time;

// test
time = new Date().getTime();
for (var i in checkList) {
    console.log('try [...].indexOf('+ checkList[i]+') === ' + arr.indexOf(checkList[i]));
}
console.log('Total: ' + (new Date().getTime() - time) + 'ms');

// test
time = new Date().getTime();
for (var i in checkList) {
    console.log('try String(...).indexOf(' + checkList[i] + ') === ' + arr_string.indexOf(checkList[i]));
}
console.log('Total: ' + (new Date().getTime() - time) + 'ms');

// test
time = new Date().getTime();
for (var i in checkList) {
    console.log('try {...}.hasOwnProperty(' + checkList[i] + ') === ' + arr_obj.hasOwnProperty(checkList[i]));
}
console.log('Total: ' + (new Date().getTime() - time) + 'ms');

// test
time = new Date().getTime();
for (var i in checkList) {
    console.log('try {...}[' + checkList[i] + '] === true === ' + (arr_obj[checkList[i]] === true));
}
console.log('Total: ' + (new Date().getTime() - time) + 'ms');
```

I believe that the best way to perform this task is `Object` with `hasOwnProperty`, but **what different ways do you know?**

Maybe I should try using other databases?

Comment: Have you defined an Index at the column which stores the number what you are searching for, in your table on MySQL?

Comment: Well if you work with a list, the time complexity is *O(n)* whereas the time complexity for an object is *O(1)*.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy yes

Comment: Can you post here you query on MySQL?

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy http://s2.micp.ru/W2I52.png

Comment: ADD AN INDEX... OK, Diego said it first, but it should be repeated until it sinks in. Show your table structure if you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It started out as a comments but it didn't fit so I post it as an answer. As other has already pointed out, use an index on the column that you want to search or sort anything by. Always. Not only in this example.

If it isn't enough then consider using some other data store like Redis that may be more efficient to handle your particular use case.

Comment: Yes, `ALTER TABLE members ADD INDEX member_id (member_id);` Accelerated the search to 0.0003 seconds for 1 element! Thanks!